# Node js mysql ending connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection

i read a lot of topic on stack overflow and original docs of node-mysql but nowhere it is clearly described how to handle connections.

i create connection in the very beginning of my script with `.createConnection(params)`everything works fine i do my last operation with db and naturally im closing it by `.end()` method the problem starts here

when another user connects my server instead of creating new connection -which i wrote in the very beginning as i told- gives me an error `Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit`

the point here i dont understand is i ended connection in previous users section end thi sis new user and script is called from the beginning

why an already ended connection cannot be re-connected is this a bug or am i doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I found out the same connection cannot be used twice so i simply added a callback inside `connection#end()` and if theres no error i set my connection variable to `null` simply something like this

```
var connection =connection?connection:mysql.createConnection(dbParams);
connection.connect(
function(err){
if(err)console.log("cannot connect due to",err);
else console.log("connected");
})

//something happens here with  db

connection.end(
function(err){
if(!err)connection=null;
else console.log(err)
});
```

And now everything works perfect